# newline in angular page converted with &lt;br/&gt

Tags: javascript, html, angular, newline

I have the following function:

```
  setLocalVariableOnAccepted(ogp, hb, responseJson) {
    if (responseJson.ofgp === undefined) {
      this.ogpStatus = 'orange';
      this.ogpStatusMsg = responseJson.ofgp + ', <br/> No change. Previous value is used';
    }
```

that fills the message in the following div:

```
 <div id="default_ogp">
        <p>
        <b>Default Offline Grace Period [minutes]</b><br>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength=7 id="default_ogp_input" size="60%" 
                  pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$" (focus)="onFocus($event)" (input)="onChangeInput($event)"
                  [(ngModel)]="ogpInteger" name="default_ogp_input" #default_ogp_input="ngModel">
            </p>
            <p id="invalid_pattern_match_ogp" class="inputValidationFailure" [hidden]="!default_ogp_input.hasError('pattern')">Invalid format</p>
            <p id="message_response_ogp" class="messageResponseBox" [style.background-color]="ogpStatus" [hidden]="!ogpStatusMsg">{{ogpStatusMsg}}</p>
    </div>
```

but once populated the label appears like:

```
Message..., <br/> No change. Previous value is used
```

so 
 is printed as string, converted in text, in fact by inspecting the code I can see that is mapped with the following ascii code: &lt ; br/ >

```
Message, &lt;br/&gt; No change. Previous value is used</p>
```

How can I change it and introduce newline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to create a pipe to sanitize your HTML.

Here is a [super simplified example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfawpv?file=app/app.component.ts)

Basically you will change this line in your HTML

```
<p id="message_response_ogp" class="messageResponseBox" 
[style.background-color]="ogpStatus" [hidden]="!ogpStatusMsg">{{ogpStatusMsg}}</p>
```

to include the pipe like so

```
<p id="message_response_ogp" class="messageResponseBox" 
[style.background-color]="ogpStatus" [hidden]="!ogpStatusMsg" 
[innerHTML]="ogpStatusMsg | sanitizeHtml"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use actual newlines:

```js
setLocalVariableOnAccepted(ogp, hb, responseJson) {
    if (responseJson.ofgp === undefined) {
      this.ogpStatus = 'orange';
      this.ogpStatusMsg = responseJson.ofgp + ', \n No change. Previous value is used';
    }
```

and set your container to display them with CSS:

```css
.messageResponseBox{
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Alternatively, using `innerHtml` should work, too:

```html
<span [innerHtml]="ogpStatusMsg"></span>
```

Comment: I'm upvoting Moritz answer since technically you were asking about "new line" and his alternative does work as expected as well, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwjvgn?file=app/app.component.ts. However, I am leaving mine as eventually you will run into situations where sanitizeHTML is needed.